# OAuth client credentential implementation in Asp.Net web api

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

When handling authentication for a server-to-server API, we really only have two options: HTTP basic auth or OAuth 2.0 client credentials.
I have created an API and now suppose various MVC Clients are going to use it .
Anyone here who have implemented it? a working demo (video or article) .
Thanks in advance.

FDI(for developers information) yestarday i asked the question about use case of OAuth and literally nobody mentioned it , it seems like there is only one use of OAuth is social logins (or where presence of third party Oauth provider is necessary, what you guys are doing here (MVP,CSharpCornerMVP) when you can't clear doubts of a newbie like me, i am really very disappointed , i have registered myself here to ask questions , my questions may seems stupid but for a newbie there is no way to learn a concept without clearing doubts)